# how to use drop down box in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have recently started working on spring MVC. In the JSPx web page I need to take the country-code from user and save it into the database. For this purpose, initially, I was using textfield for user input. The code is as below-

```
<fieldset class="fieldset" >
  <div class="fields">
    <field:input field="country" id="label_organisation_view_country" disabled="${!isAddOrganizationView}"/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have made an enum (public enum Country) containing the list of country-codes. Now, I want to use drop-down for getting the country-code instead of textbox, using the created enum.

Can anyone please let me know how to get it or redirect me to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

using the spring form tag, that requires this :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

you can do something like:

```
<form:form name="myFRM" id="myFRM" action="${myURL}" method="POST" modelAttribute="myBackingObject">
    <form:select path="myCountry" id="MyCountry" name='MyCountry'>
      <form:options items="${countries}" itemLabel="yourMethodForDisplayNameInEnum"/> 
    </form:select>
```

and in controller :

```
model.addAttribute("countries", CountryEnum.values());
model.addAttribute("myBackingObject", yourPojoContaingFieldMyCountry);
```

Check out the docs :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

and specifically mvc

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: can you please detail the attributes like - what does path, modelAttribute do etc. so it will be clearer...

Comment: @ankitrai have a look at the docs, I've given you a good starting point